# Calculate: $\int_A\mbox{ div }v\, d(x,y,z)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> > $A:=\left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x^2+y^2\leq 1,0\leq z\leq 1\right\},$
> >     $v\colon\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^3, (x,y,z)\longmapsto (x^3,x^2y,zx^2)$.
> >     Calculate
> >     $\int_A\mbox{div }v\, d^3x$.

I did the following:

$$
\mbox{div }v=5x^2,
$$

Parametrization of $A$:

$$
\Psi\colon [0,1]\times [-\pi,\pi)\times [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^3, (u,v,w)\longmapsto\begin{pmatrix}u\cos v\\u\sin v\\w\end{pmatrix}
$$

Then:

$$
\int_A 5x^2\, d(x,y,z)=5\int_0^1\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_0^1 u^2\cos^2 v u\, dw\, dv\, du=5/4 \pi
$$

But is this correct? To my knowledge the result should be $\pi$ and not $\frac{5}{4}\pi$.

Comment: If you are not sure, you can check yourself with the hepl of Ostrogradsky-Gauss theorem. Those integrals must coincide.

Comment: I calculated the integral $\int_{\partial A}\langle v,n\rangle\, dS$, too. I got $\pi$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simpler to use the symmetry, I think.

$$\iint_{x^2+y^2\leqslant 1} x^2\,dx\,dy = \frac12 \iint_{x^2+y^2\leqslant 1} x^2+y^2 \,dx\,dy = \frac12 \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} r^2 \,d\varphi\, r\,dr = \pi \int_0^1 r^3\,dr = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Since the integrand does not depend on $z$, that integral only contributes a constant factor $1$, and your result is correct. Perhaps there was an error in copying the field $v$ and the actual divergence is $4x^2$ instead of $5x^2$?

Comment: The problem is the following: The following integral has to be calculated: $\int_{\partial A}\langle v,n\rangle \, dS$ first by using the Gaussian integral theoreom (this is what I used here) and then by calculating it as an surface integral. But when I calculated it as a surface integral, I got $\pi$. So I wonder why i got two different results, $\frac{5}{4}\pi$ and $\pi$.

Comment: I think I forgot the surface integral of bottom and top of the cylinder :D And this gives the missing summand $\pi/4$.